# Is the prefix of power of three in binary representation contains all possible number combinations?

Tags: combinatorics, binary, bit-strings

Let $S(x)$ be the string of positive integer $x$ in binary representation.

Conjecture: **For any positive integer $x$, there exists an integer $k$ such that string $S(x)$ is a prefix of string $S(3^k)$.**

Example, for $x=5, S(x) = 101$, then $k=4, S(3^4) = 1010001$.
The program has verified no exception for $x \le 2^9$.

Remark: "The Tao produced One; One produced Two; Two produced Three; Three produced All things."

Comment: Some more context would be helpful. Is this an exercise you've been given (and if so, what's the source)? Is it a conjecture of your own which you don't know to be true?

Comment: It is a cojecture of my own, the question has relation with the 3n+1 problem in which the power of three takes important role.

Answer (score 2):

Write
$$3^k=2^\ell\cdot\xi_k,\qquad\ell\in{\mathbb N}, \ 1<\xi_k<2\ .$$
Taking the $\log_2$ on both sides we obtain
$$k\log_2 3=\ell+\alpha_k$$
with $0<\alpha_k:=\log_2\xi_k<1$. It is well known that the $\alpha_k$ are uniformly distributed modulo $1$, in particular they are dense in $[0,1]$. This implies that the $\xi_k$ are dense in $[1,2]$, and this shows that all finite binary sequences occur as prefix of suitable numbers $3^k$.